# (Still roblox related)Countdown stays at 15 and frame does not appear for player 2 when they join after the countdown ends

Tags: roblox

(Yes i know this is getting quite old but im new to scripting...)

So i have this problem again where if player 2 joins the game after the countdown ends the countdown number stays 15 and the MapVotingFrame does not appear for player 2 but only happens to player 1(Like my first question but reversed) Here's the script for the 3rd time:

script:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("IntermissonEvent")

local secondsRemaining = 15

for t = secondsRemaining, 0, -1 do
    remoteEvent:FireAllClients(t)
    wait(1)
end
```

localscript:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("IntermissonEvent")

local function onTimerUpdate(seconds)
       script.Parent.Text = tostring(seconds)

if seconds == 0 then
    script.Parent.Parent.MapVotingFrame.Visible = true
end
end

remoteEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(onTimerUpdate)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to be more clear in your questions, I think I understood the problem but you should still include more context

Your main problem is in

```
local secondsRemaining = 15
```

and

```
for t = secondsRemaining, 0, -1 do
   remoteEvent:FireAllClients(t)
   wait(1)
end
```

It stays at 15 because you don't change the value of secondsRemaining at all.
in the server script change it to;

```
for t = secondsRemaining, 0, -1 do
   secondsRemaining = secondsRemaining - 1
   remoteEvent:FireAllClients(t)
   wait(1)
end
```

Comment: `secondsRemaining` is only used to initialize the t variable in the for loop. The `t`variable properly decrements down to 0.